# Can Starship become the cheapest rocket even in expendable version?

Tags: spacex-starship, spacex-super-heavy

Given SpaceX is streamlining the mass production of Starships and raptors, can it turn out that Starship would become the cheapest rocket compared to other rockets for its load even if used as expendable?

Comment: The lunar lander Starship will be an expendable form of Starship, and is not planned to have heat tiles to reenter Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: @Sheldon I meant expendable first stage.

Answer (score 8):

Given that we don't *really* know yet what StarShip's cargo ability is, that we have only a rough idea of the engine cost, have only wild armwavey ideas of what the actual incremental manufacturing cost of the rocket is, and have absolutely no clue on what the ground support costs will be (not even where it will be launched from, Boca Chica is *only* the test centre), and the creator of the StarShip has adamantly sworn that it will never be used in expendable form....

I'd have to say the definitive answer to your question is..... **Green with Blue Polka Dots.**

<sub>a.k.a. Insufficient data for a meaningful answer</sub>

Comment: "the creator of the StarShip has adamantly sworn that it will never be used in expendable form": It'll likely take a fair number of launches before second stage recovery works, the HLS Starship is essentially expendable, the "depot" Starship may be expendable or at least have a very limited operating lifetime, many of the Mars craft are expected to stay there, and Musk has specifically mentioned using expendable stripped-down Starships to throw interplanetary probes. It's not yet clear what that would cost or how common it would be, but it is an anticipated use case.